# Android search dialog in landscape mode

Tags: android, search, user-interface

I'm using searchable.xml to search the email. When in landscape mode, the ui background is showing as a white screen, please give me solution for the issue.

Thanks,
Sneha

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as 'sneha' and it gets fixed by setting "**flagNoExtractUi**" ime
option for the **SearchView**. i.e.

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

Answer (score 1):

With SearchView, if you don't want to show full-screen keyboard while in Landscape mode (rather show normal keyboard), IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI and IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN flags need to add in Ime options. You can do it within your Java code in onCreateOptionsMenu(..) method,

```
searchView = (SearchView) .... // get or find your searchView here
searchView.setImeOptions(searchView.getImeOptions() | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI | EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

create a folder res/layout-land and place the searchable.xml inside it with the layout that you want. While changing the orientation from Portrait to landscape the corresponding XML will be considered for the UI.

Comment: hi actually when i switch to landscape mode it is taking entire screen like click on search menu white background is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to provide search suggest options in **searchable.xml**. For example:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" 

    android:searchSuggestAuthority="shelves"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://shelves/books" />
```

Simply, **android:searchSuggestAuthority=""** is enough if you don't need searchSuggest.
Hope it helps.