# Android: Search Tool in landscape orientation

Tags: android, search

The Search Tool in StatusBar changes completely when in Landscape orientation.

It happens only when Search Bar is expanded.

Please see the screenshots. 
[image: Portrait Mode]

[image: Landscape Mode]

**EDIT**

CODE:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    int options = searchView.getImeOptions();
    searchView.setImeOptions(options| EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);

    searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()) );
    searchView.setIconified(true);
    searchView.clearFocus();

    return true;
}
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:searchSuggestAuthority="Search in a Collection/Book or Favorites"
    />
```

And menu

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="Search in a Collection/Book or Favorites"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075719/android-search-dialog-in-landscape-mode

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31456029/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-having-fullscreen-searchview-keyboard-on-landscape

Comment: None of them seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Finally fixed it. Put `android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"` in your SEARCHABLE xml if you are using `widget` `SearchView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch|flagNoExtractUi|flagNoFullscreen"
/>
```